# Can these sets of matrices solve the given questions

Tags: matrices

Assume $X$, $Y$, $Z$, $W$, and $P$ are matrices of order $2 \times n$, $3 \times k$, $2 \times p$, $n \times 3$, and $p \times k$ respectively:

> $$X =  \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} &  a_{12}  & \ldots & a_{1n}\\ a_{21}  & 
>  a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n}\\ \end{pmatrix} $$

---

> $$Y = 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a_{11} &  a_{12}  & \ldots & a_{1k}\\
> a_{21}  &  a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2k}\\
> a_{31} & a_{32} & \ldots & a_{3k}\\
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

---

> $$Z = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} &  a_{12}  & \ldots & a_{1p}\\ a_{21}  &   a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2p}\\ \end{pmatrix} $$

---

> $$W= \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} &  a_{12}   & a_{13}\\ a_{21}  &  a_{22} & a_{23}\\ \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots\\ a_{n1}  &   a_{n2}  &
> a_{n3} \end{pmatrix} $$

---

> $$P = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11}  & \ldots & a_{1k}\\ a_{21}   & \ldots & a_{2k}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\ a_{p1} &\ldots & a_{pk}
> \end{pmatrix} $$

---

---

Now, the questions:

Q1. What will be the restrictions on $n$, $k$, and $p$ so that $PY + WY$ will be defined?

Q2. If $n$ = $p$, then what is the order of the matrix $7X^2 - 5Z^3$?

Can the above said questions be solved using a logical approach? If so, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1.** $WY$ is a $n\times k$ matrix; to add it to $PY$, the latter must be defined, and be a $n\times k$ matrix too. But it is the product of a $p\times k$ matrix by a $3\times k$, hence it is defined if and only if $k=3$, and in such a case is a $p\times 3$ matrix. Thus, to add $WY$ and $PY$, the condition $n=p$  is also  required.

**Q2.** Only square matrices of the same order can be added and multiplied. $Z^3$  exists if and only if $p=2$, in which case $X^2$ also  exists – and $7X^2-5Z^3$.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a beautiful solution. I've pressed that gray tick now turning it into a beautiful green colour :)

Answer (score 1):

For part 1, we know that matrices A and B can only be multiplied if A has dimensions q x t and B has dimensions t x r (q and r can be anything)  and then AB will have dimension q x r.  Furthermore, two matrices can only be added if they have the same dimenions
Thus for PY + WY to be defined we know that k = 3 and n = p.

For the second part in order for this to be defined we dont even need to know that n = p.  You can not take the square (or cube) of a non square matrix, so both X and Z must be 2x2 matrices.

Comment: Part 2 of yours confused a little. @Bernard explained that one better. Thanks though :)

Comment: No worries, we are all here to help